# How to POST Date to table

Tags: php, mysql

I am tryng to POST a date to my table but it wont get it.
i creat my table like this:

```
        mysql_select_db("kiracilar", $con);
    $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE kira
    (
        id INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
        KIRACI_ID INTEGER,
        kira INTEGER,
        odeme BOOL DEFAULT 0,
        tarih DATE DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )";
    mysql_query($sql2,$con)
```

and after creating my table i post it and send it to my table like this:

```
$date = $_POST["date"];
$query2= "INSERT INTO kira (KIRACI_ID,kira,odeme,tarih) VALUES ('$id','$kira','$odeme','$date')";
```

what I do is POST for example "2012-09-27" but it wont take it. there is nothing wrong with the posting because when I echo it, it shows what I have posted. In my table when I go in my database it shows the default like "0000-00-00" and that is I think correct...( dont look at the other things they are functioning right )
Im using php5,phpmyadmin.
If you could help me it would be great.

according to some answers I get. I also added this :

```
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');

if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}

if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}
```

this works fine.
But still i cant get my date to my table.

Comment: `echo $query2;` outputs what?

Comment: your date field and format of the date string you enter ??

Comment: it'll be much better if you'd parse the string to DATE before inserting it like `$date = strtotime($_POST["date"])`, this should work for you..!

Comment: vishal- getting the same error as i answered to Geert.

Comment: @vishal: why you want to do that? Pointless.

Comment: @itachi PHP isn't strict with types but I believe its always better to  go with proper data type to avoid injection attacks and prone errors; similar solution also proposed by **Mihai** here with proper update.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following before your query:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: when i do this im getting an error as following : It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. bla bla . use date_default_timezone_set(). no idea what it is

Comment: @Mohtje61 [The PHP manual is your friend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Your time zone is not set, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php (Hint: PeerGoal.com's answer ;-))

Comment: Doing : date_default_timezone_set('Turkey/Istanbul');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get(); and still error

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `strtotime()`:

```
$date = strtotime($_POST["date"]);
$query2= "INSERT INTO kira (KIRACI_ID,kira,odeme,tarih) VALUES ('$id','$kira','$odeme',FROM_UNIXTIME('".$date."'))";
```

Comment: getting error like I replied to everyone. and when i set my timezone still getting error.

Comment: you can suspend that notice. `$date = @strtotime($_POST["date"]);`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d', $_POST["date"]);
```

Comment: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for '3.0/DST' instead in

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Date/Time object?

```
$datetime = new DateTime( $_POST["date"]);
$date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$query2= "INSERT INTO kira (KIRACI_ID,kira,odeme,tarih) VALUES ('$id','$kira','$odeme','$date')";
```

Comment: thnx for answer. it has no errors. but still it doesnt set the date i post into my table.

Comment: have you tried opening phpmyadmin and manually entering the SQL (for example)
`INSERT INTO kira (KIRACI_ID,kira,odeme,tarih) VALUES (1,2,true,'2012-09-27')`